# Hibernate analogue for jdbc statement.setBinaryStream

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I had below jdbc snippet which i want to convert using Native query in hibernate.

Problem: This is my jdbc Code:

```java
{
   statement = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CCM_JIGSAW_FILES (FILE_ID,FILE_FOR,FILE_CONTENT) 
                    VALUES (?,?,?)");
   ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);//fileContent is byte[]
   statement.setString(1, file_id);
   statement.setString(2, licenseType);
   statement.setBinaryStream(3,in,fileContent.length);
   statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Solution tried: Tried with hibernate but could not no luck

```java
{
   String insertSqlQuery = "INSERT INTO CCM_JIGSAW_FILES (FILE_ID,FILE_FOR,FILE_CONTENT) VALUES (?,?,?)";
   inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);

   Query insertQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(insertSqlQuery);
   insertQuery.setParameter(1, fileId);
   insertQuery.setParameter(2, licenseType);
   insertQuery.setParameter(3, inputStream);// Here i am getting runtime exception.
   insertQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not determine a type for
class: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
```

How can i convert `statement.setBinaryStream(3,in,fileContent.length)` into hibernate?
Note: Data type of `FILE_CONTENT` in database is `Blob`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have POJO Class for CCM_JIGSAW_FILES table and Data type of File_Content in your POJO Class should be `byte[]`.

You can directly save byte[] in File_Content using setter method.

```
PojoObject.setterMethod(fileContent);
```

[Refer this example](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-binary-data-and-blob-mapping-example)

Comment: While this is useful for small files, it requires that the whole blob be stored in memory, which can be a problem if you have more than maybe 400MB of data.  Assuming that is why the asker is asking about streams specifically.